# Create overlay spectrograms using plt.imshow()

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am trying to create two overlaying spectrogram, in order to compare their difference.

The whole plot will contain 4 subplots, which `(221) = A`, `(223) = B`, `(222) = A+B`

I used `cmap` to set the color of A & B, and hope the mixed plot can keep the same color as separated images.

The first instinct is to just call `ax3.imshow()` twice, but it doesn't work.

```py
fig = plt.figure()

# SP1
ax1 = fig.add_subplot(221)
cm1 = plt.cm.Reds
cm1.set_under('white')
ax1.imshow(spec1, vmin = 0.1, cmap = cm1)

# SP2
ax2 = fig.add_subplot(223)
cm2 = plt.cm.Blues
cm2.set_under('white')
ax2.imshow(spec2, vmin = 0.1, cmap = cm2)


# mix
ax3 = fig.add_subplot(222)

ax3.imshow(spec1, vmin = 0.1, cmap = cm1)
ax3.imshow(spec2, vmin = 0.1, cmap = cm2)
```

Can someone share some advice? Thanks.

Comment: A common way to do this is to subtract or divide the two spectrograms and then display the difference image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

how about setting transparency:

```
ax3 = fig.add_subplot(222)

ax3.imshow(spec1, vmin = 0.1, cmap = cm1, alpha=0.5)
ax3.imshow(spec2, vmin = 0.1, cmap = cm2, alpha=0.5)
```

Comment: this works, the only disadvantage is that the pattern now seems less clear

Comment: not knowing what your images look like, you could set a higher alpha for both. background would still be transparent. Alternatively, follow Jody Klymak's comment and use a colormap like bwr or seismic

Comment: Thanks, I did tried that. The result is acceptable now